# SQL Email Trigger - inserted row

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger which should shoot a mail as soon a record is added to a said table. For this purpose I have created a the following trigger, which is sort of catering my requirement:

```
ALTER  TRIGGER [dbo].[EMAIL_ALERT_NEW]
ON [dbo].[APTCR_LOG]
after  insert 
as
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

 DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
SELECT AUDTUSER, NAMERMIT ,AMTRMITTC,IDRMIT FROM APTCR_LOG inserted 
    SELECT @body += CHAR(13) +++ CHAR(10) +++ RTRIM(AUDTUSER)  +++ RTRIM(NAMERMIT) +++RTRIM(AMTRMITTC) +RTRIM(IDRMIT) FROM APTCR_LOG inserted;

  --SELECT NAMERMIT, AUDTUSER ,AMTRMITTC FROM APTCR_LOG WHERE AMTRMITTC > 100000
BEGIN
--SELECT AUDTUSER, NAMERMIT ,AMTRMITTC,IDRMIT FROM APTCR_LOG inserted  WHERE AMTRMITTC > 100000.000
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

      @recipients = 'ublaze@gmail.com', 
      @profile_name = 'default',
      @subject = 'NEW PAYMENT', 
      @body = @body;
END
end
```

The issue is it's sending all the records on the table where I just need the last record which was added in to the table.

Can somebody please help with this situation?

Comment: This isn't very clear. What do you mean it is sending all the rows in the table? It will concatenate all the rows in the inserted table. Isn't that what you want? Not sure why you have all those +++ in there. Or why you have an errant select statement.

Comment: WHat you do when there are multiple inserts in one command? You fail basic SQL here - a trigger can have multiple rows.

Comment: Well all I want to achieve is trigger a mail for the lasr inserted row , but right now all the rows are being sent to the mail :(